# view the preview of the image before form submit

Tags: php, javascript, image-upload

I am creating a social website.There is provision for storing images during registration of users.I want to display the preview of the image when the user uploads the image,before the form get submitted.Please help me.

This is my code in registration section

```
<form action="insert_scene.php" 
 method="post" id="sceneform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="image">Scene Flyer:</label>
<img src="" width="120" height="130" alt="Scene Pic" />
<a href="" onclick="return uploadimg()" > Upload</a></li>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display:none;" />
 </form>
```

The javascript content is

```
   function uploadimg()
{
    var uploader = document.getElementById('file');
    uploader.click();
    return false;
}
```

This is the segment of code in the `insert_scene.php`(Actually the following segment of code is placed in another file which is being included in the `insert_scene.php`)

```
<?php 
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
ini_set("post_max_size", "10M");
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "10M");
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
  $fileN = '';
 echo 'File Size:' .($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024);
}
else
{

$maxImgSize=($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024);

if($maxImgSize>=5121 || $maxImgSize==0){

  $fileN = '';
}
else{

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

  $fileN="upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

  while(file_exists($fileN)){
      $fileN="upload/" . md5($fileN).$_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }

  rename("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"], $fileN);


      }
    } 
   ?>
   $scene_flyer = $fileN;
```

After posting the  form,`$scene_flyer` gets the image address.But i would like to display the preview before the form in the first page gets submitted.Please help me.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, Before posting the form image is still in local machine. but you can use AJAX and show the image.

Comment: @Prasanth Bendra How does the preview of the image is shown in facebook then??

Comment: As I said you can do it using AJAX, When user selects the image, it will be uploaded to server, and will be shown there. User will submit the form later

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Can you suggest me any code snippets

Comment: Try this : http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improve your code and use jQuery uploadify.

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Then write some simple code in the event OnUploadSuccess:

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/

Comment: This can be used for image upload also.Actually i need to display the image also

Comment: The php upload script can return OK:http://your.site.com/img/temp/picture_uploaded_XXXXXXX.jpg

Inside OnUploadSuccess event, just check that data begins with "OK:" then use the temp uploaded image url to change image.src.

$("#preview_image").attr("src","http://your.site.com/img/temp/picture_uploaded_XXXXXXX.jpg");

Comment: We dont need any jquery libraries for this??

Comment: Yes, you need it. Check uploadify examples. They are very clear!

Comment: I have seen that,But it is using flash.I am not supposed to implement flash

Comment: Eenthough it is not suitable for me,I can accept your answer coz any one who need the above requirement can use it

Comment: There is also a pure HTML5 version. Check if it suits your needs.